# Is there any way to add calback functions to charts in highcharter?

Tags: r, r-highcharter

The problem I'm trying to solve using highcharter is exactly the same as the one described in [this issue](https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=39798).

I have a half-donut chart whose container takes as much space as the whole circle of the pie would take if it existed, and I want to resize it to just cover the space actually being rendered as a half-donut in order to put other elements below it.

In the demo posted as solution to the original problem ([link here](https://jsfiddle.net/ppotaczek/utgff74u/)). A callback function is used that calls the `setSize` method of the `Highcharts.Chart` object ([link to the method here](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#setSize)).

Is there any way to describe an equivalent functionality using highcharter?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

It's best to do it with chart.events.load, then you can write your JS function there: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.load

Here you can see how to do it:

```
library('highcharter')
highchart() %>%
  hc_add_series(
    type = "pie",
    innerSize = '50%',
    startAngle = -90,
    endAngle = 90,
    size = '150%',
    dataLabels = list(enabled = FALSE), 
    data = list(5, 4, 3, 5)
  ) %>%
  hc_chart(events = list(load = JS("function() {
    var chart = this;
    chart.setSize(chart.plotSizeX, chart.plotSizeX - 700);
  }")))
```

Comment: That is exactly right, thank you very much for taking the time to answer. Really appreciate it.

I didn't see an equivalent of the [Highcharts.Chart](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart) class constructor implemented in highcharter. Since it was there where I saw the callback, I thought that maybe there wasn't a way to call it. Had I looked more carefully into the callback argument, I would have found 
that an equivalent way to define the behavior was using the option you proposed.
Thanks again :)